# Loop through workbooks in a folder to copy and insert cells into a master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have to loooop through workbooks in a folder that start with the phrase "BATCH" to copy and insert the copied cells into one sheet in a master workbook.
I've tried to use an example I found online but it isn't working. It doesn't do anything.

```
Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()
Dim lCount As Long
Dim wbResults As Workbook
Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook
With Application.FileSearch
.NewSearch
.LookIn = "C:\Path"
.FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks
.Filename = "BATCH*.xls"
If .Execute > 0 Then
For lCount = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.FoundFiles(lCount), UpdateLinks:=0)

Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("Data").Range("B23:Z38").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Rows("1:16").Insert Shift:=xlDown

wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next lCount
End If
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'd also like to be able to have one file that can be dropped into any folder to perform this task.

Comment: You are copying but not pasting.

Comment: "I'd also like to be able to have one file that can be dropped into any folder to perform this task." What is preventing you from attempting this? Put the code in a workbook and have it reference the current directly.

Comment: I'd have to change the folder path every time. What I meant was that I want it to work without having to open it and change the path every time.

Comment: Why would you need to modify the path? `ActiveWorkbook.Path` will refer to the current directory. If you use this then you could just move the file to another directory and run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Andy G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620444/andy-g) pointed in his comment, you forgot pasting. Your coude shoud be

```
Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("Data").Range("B23:Z38").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Rows("1:16").Insert Shift:=xlDown
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Paste
```

**EDIT:** since `Application.FileSearch` [is gone as of Excel 2007](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/applicationfilesearch-not-working/771afb4f-d948-4a37-ac8f-4366336a41fc), you could try this alternative approach using VBA's `Dir()` function:

```
Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()
    Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myMask As String
    Dim fnResults As String
    Dim wbResults As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook
    myPath = "C:\Path"
    myMask = "BATCH*.xls"

    fnResults = Dir(myPath & "\" & myMask) 'Get 1st match
    Do While fnResults <> ""
        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(myPath & "\" & fnResults, 0)
        Workbooks(fnResults).Worksheets("Data").Range("B23:Z38").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Rows("1:16").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Paste
        fnResults = Dir 'Get next match
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed my code but it doesn't run. I get an error
on the line
With Application.FileSearch
It says the object doesn't support this action :(

Comment: For that error, I did a research and found out `Application.FileSearch` exists no longer, last version it works is Excel 2003.